# Http service POST

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this GET data (http service) in my application on angular 2:

```
    private _url = "http://10.77.7.77/monitoring/api/v1/services/list";

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    getServices(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

And everything is OK, but now my task is create a POST data, with another URL:

```
private _url2 = 'http://10.77.7.77/monitoring/api/v1/action/stop';
```

id - number of service this json:

```
[{
"nodename": "10.46.2.152",
"servicelist": [{
    "id": "3827aa4b204fc2e122f452c1c1ceeaf15109364698d5d0f2153efa6e9487a968",
    "name": "Nginx",
    "status": "Online",
    "servicecontrolled": true
}]
```

I wrote this POST data:

```
postServices(post: { title: string, status: string, id: number }): Observable<any> {
        let _url3 = `${this._url2}/${post.id}`
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const body = JSON.stringify(post);
        return this._http.post(_url3, body, post)
            .map(res => res.json())
    }
```

with this event

```
onPost(title: string, body: string, id: string) {
  this._service.postServices({title: title, body: body, id: +id})
    .subscribe(
      response => this.response = response,
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

and this my template:

```
<button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled" 
[style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled 
 == 'true' ? 'green' : 'orange'"
 class="btn btn-warning"
 (click)="onPost()">
 {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | toOnOff }}
 </button>
```

And now i have some error `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: We wrote a web service today. When we tried to get a return value which we know that it is not in the database  it returned internal server error. Maybe the value is not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post JSON data, just use the following:

```
// From RC2
postServices(post: { title: string, body: string, id: number }): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(this._url2, post)
        .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Angular2 will set automatically for you the `application/json` content type and serialize your post object (`JSON.stringify`).

If you want to serialize by your own JSON content (before RC2 excluded), you need to add the content type explicitly:

```
postServices(post: { title: string, body: string, id: number }): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post(this._url2, post, { headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: i have error in `return this._http.post(this._url2, post, { headers })` -> visual code wrote `argument of type is not assignable`

Comment: which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: angular 2 rc1, error in 'post' and log `argument of type is not assignable`

Comment: So you need to set explicitly the content type header. I updated my answer with the hint regarding version... With RC1, only input as text is supported at the level of the `post` method.

Comment: but how i can bind my `_url2=...` with json `id`?

Comment: You could use this: `let url2 = \`${this.url}/${post.id}\`` (ES6 backticks).

Comment: I update my question, and now i have this error -> `http://10.77.7.77/monitoring/api/v1/action/stop/NaN 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo but in `this._service.postServices({title: title, body: body, id: +id})`, I would remove the `+`...

Comment: If i remove `+`, show same error -> `argument of type is not assignable`

Comment: I guess that you try to provide a string for the id whereas it's a number in the declaration. You could try: `post: { title: string, body: string, id: string }`...

Comment: again this error...maybe i have mistake in event `onPost()`?

Comment: Could you show me how you use `onPost` from the template? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! In fact, you don't provide parameter to the `onPost` method: `(click)="onPost()"` whereas it expects some...

Comment: Something like that: `(click)="onPost(service_rec.name, service_rec.status, service_rec.id)"`

Comment: Thank you, but i remove `service_rec.name` to `service_rec.title`, and now, everything ist working!) thanks again